# Display all tables for different schema

Tags: sql, oracle

I have executed this query to show all tables into my db

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME, num_rows counter 
FROM all_tables;
```

but the db has got different schema and I want to execute this query for each of these.
I already tried to select one table for every schema and the only way is from the main schema with this syntax

```
SELECT *
FROM X.TABLE
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT DISTINCT OWNER, OBJECT_NAME 
  FROM DBA_OBJECTS
WHERE OBJECT_TYPE = 'TABLE'
 AND OWNER = '[some other schema]'
```